# A way to retrieve #1 trending YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm making a website for an assignment in school, and I need to find a way to retrieve the [#1 trending video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending?bp=6gQJRkVleHBsb3Jl), Is there any possible way to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the YouTube api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

The relevant filter would be "chart": "mostPopular"

The example provided is:

```js
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.videos.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
      "part": [
        "snippet,contentDetails,statistics"
      ],
      "chart": "mostPopular",
      "regionCode": "US"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Comment: The OP may be interested in knowing the filter to use that is `chart=mostPopular`.

Comment: Yes, I will edit it.

Comment: By the way as you added some code, I am ok that the API key is required to make the API calls, however there isn't any need to authenticate using auth2 etc...